# how can I write palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write a return function.
I wrote the first condition correctly that if it checks all the first and last words and reaches one word but my result is `None`. How can I fix it?

```
 def palindrome(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
        return True
    if string[0] == string[-1]:
        return palindrome(string[1:-1])


answ = palindrome('kjhhjk')
print(answ)
```

Comment: Running you script I get the result `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither of your conditions is true `None` is returned (which is not the same as `False`.

Here I added a final return statement to circumvent this.

```
def palindrome(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
        return True
    if string[0] == string[-1]:
        return palindrome(string[1:-1])
    return False  # this is important!

answ = palindrome('kjhhjk')
print(answ)
```

Comment: can you get a picture where is it? i am so noob

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined (explicitly) what `palindrome` should return when `string[0]` does *not* equal `string[-1]`. Aside from the base case, a palindrome has *two* conditions it has to satisfy, which means you can use `and` to combine those two checks into one.

```
def palindrom(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
        return True
    return string[0] == string[-1] and palindrome(string[1:-1])
```

Now, your function either returns `True` in the base case, or it returns the value (true or false) of the condition that checks both the end words and the middle of the string.